# loop a stored procedure to insert an array of string values, only the first record is saved - why?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Environment PHP 5.3.5 phpMyAdmin 3.3.9

I have two procedures, one which completes a straight forward double insert. The second procedure is looped and call for each value of an array which calls the LAST INSERT ID value based upon the first stored procedure since that table has has an auto-increment id column.

For some reason the multiple calls to the second procedure is only storing the the first v
value of the array. I cannot get the second value in the array to be stored.

First procedure is like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1(
    IN varData1 LONGTEXT,
    IN userID BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO table1 (datetime_created) VALUES (NOW());
    INSERT INTO table2 (ID, userID, data, date_created) 
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), userID, varData1, NOW());
END
DELIMITER;
```

Second Procedure is like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc2(
IN ID2 BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO relationshipMany2ManyTable(id1, id2) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ID2);
END
DELIMITER;
```

From PHP I am calling each procedure like so:

```
$model->proc1($pmTextArea, $userID);
$model->proc2($commaSeparatedArray);
```

I'll skip over detailing the function of proc1, it works, and the stored procedure is displayed above. proc2 works for the first execution, but subsequent executions appear to be not working.

```
public function proc2($String_array)
{
    try {
        $value_array = explode(",", $String_array);
        foreach($value_array AS $value)
        {
            $statement =  $this->_dbh->prepare("Call proc2(?)");
            $statement->bindParam(1, trim($value));
            echo 'bind value '.$value.' to table';
            $statement->execute();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

If the string array I pass in to proc2 is:

```
"1, 2, 3"
```

I see the echo statements to be:

```
bind value 1 to table
bind value 2 to table
bind value 3 to table
```

But only the first value is inserted. The other values are not being inserted. I am new to this, especially to the stored procedures. I believe it has to deal with the LAST INSERT ID, but that relates to the last table with an auto-increment value, which is found in table2 of proc1.

1. I have tried completing this process in a single stored procedure using loops but I have been unsuccessful.
2. I have also tried to return the value of the LAST INSERT ID in the first procedure so that it could be used when handed into the second procedure.

These attempts have failed for me for I am still learning, and I have this working and looking to continue down this road. Debugging stored procedures is challenging enough using the phpMyAdmin.

Can anyone tell me why the second insert will not occur? What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: If id1 is the primary key, inserting LAST_INSERT_ID() as that row should cause some sort of error. You should be able to set that column to auto increment if you want each id1 to be 1 greater than the previous (consecutive numbers).

Comment: just reviewed my table apparently it was set to be a primary key, it was supposed to be a foreign key. I am going to update the table and try it again. It could be the subsequent inserts were failing due to this configuration issue. I'll post back here shortly if that is the solution.

Comment: So everything posted here is logically correct. 

It was Michael Wheeler that mentioned if id1 is a Primary Key.

This made me review the database. The field id1 was set to primary. So the many to many relationship could never be applied to this table when it should be capable of doing so. 

The primary key was removed while the correct foreign key relationship was added. Now all values in the array are being stored with the correct relationship to id1.